# combine same index of array?

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have following $_POST array

```
array(5) {
  ["addcatagory"]=>
  string(8) "CATEGORY"
  ["reg_admin_id"]=>
  string(2) "25"
  ["subcatagory"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "SUB CAT 1"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "sub cat 2"
  }
  ["subCat_Detais"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "AAAAAAAAA"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "BBBBBBBB"
  }
  ["submit"]=>
  string(15) "Submit Catagory"
}
```

and

```
array(1) {
  ["subCatFile1"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "2.jpg"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "3.jpg"
      [2]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    ["type"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "image/jpeg"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "image/jpeg"
      [2]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(18) "/var/tmp/phpN5ENy2"
      [1]=>
      string(18) "/var/tmp/phpRyJdcc"
      [2]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    ["error"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      int(0)
      [1]=>
      int(0)
      [2]=>
      int(4)
    }
    ["size"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      int(65101)
      [1]=>
      int(49550)
      [2]=>
      int(0)
    }
  }
}
```

now what i want to achieve is combine 0 index of subcatagory and subcat_details in one array and of 1 index of subcatagory and subcat_details in second array and so on...
how can i achieve this?? is it even possible??

**Expectations**

```
array( 'name' => 'SUB CAT 1',
       'details' => 'AAAAAAAAA',
       'image_name'=>'2.jpg'
     );

array( 'name' => 'SUB CAT 2',
       'details' => 'BBBBBBB',
       'image_name'=>'2.jpg'
     );
```

Comment: Please show your expected output.

Comment: will `count($_POST["subcatagory"])` always be the same as `count($_POST["subCat_Detais"])`?

Comment: @Sean yeah i will make their count always equal..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a simple `foreach()` loop -

```
$newArray = [];
foreach($_POST["subcatagory"] as $key => $value) {
    $newArray[] = array("name" => $_POST["subcatagory"][$key],
                        "details" => $_POST["subCat_Detais"][$key]);
}
```

As @CharlotteDunois mentioned, you could also use an `for()` loop, as long as you have sequential keys, with no keys missing -

```
$newArray = [];
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST["subcatagory"]);$i++) {
    $newArray[] = array("name" => $_POST["subcatagory"][$i],
                        "details" => $_POST["subCat_Detais"][$i]);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a for loop be better here, as you just use the key?

Comment: sean if i would like to offer a beer for that. works like a charm ;)

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I think 'better' is subjective. I typically do `foreach()`, as it prevents issues if the arrays don't have sequential keys. If array values are added and/or deleted dynamically via javascript, there is a possibility you would have a missing key.

Comment: @Sean how would i do if i want to add $_FILES array also ,see edited question if you can help..

Comment: It looks like your `$_FILES["subCatFile1"]` has the same structure, so you would use `$_FILES["subCatFile1"]["name"][$key]` (using the `$key` in the foreach example) or `$_FILES["subCatFile1"]["name"][$i]` (using the `$i` in the for example).